# In GCD, is there a way to tell if the current queue is concurrent or not?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

In GCD, is there a way to tell if the current queue is concurrent or not?
I'm current attempting to perform a delayed save on some managed object contexts but I need to  make sure that the queue the code is currently executed on is thread-safe (in a synchronous queue).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you actually have to determine whether or not the queue passed in to you is serial or concurrent, you've almost certainly designed things incorrectly.  Typically, an API will hide an internal queue as an implementation detail (in your case, your shared object contexts) and then enqueue operations against its internal queue in order to achieve thread safety.  When your API takes a block and a queue as parameters, however, then the assumption is that the passed-in block can be safely scheduled (async) against the passed-queue (when, say, an operation is complete) and the rest of the code is factored appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, assuming you're doing the work in an [NSOperation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) subclass:

```
[myOperation isConcurrent] //or self, if you're actually in the NSOperation
```

If you need to ensure some operations are always executed synchronously, you can create a specific operation queue and set its maximum concurrent operations to 1.

```
NSOperationQueue * synchronousQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[synchronousQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
```

GCD takes some planning ahead. The only other way I can think of is to observe the value `isExecuting` (or similar) on your `NSOperation` objects. Check out [this reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002252-BAJEAIEE) on that. This solution would be more involved, so I hope the other one works for you.

Comment: I think my issue is a level deeper. I'm already executing code inside of a queue and am trying to get information about the current running GCD queue and whether it is concurrent or not.

Comment: Ok, check that out. There's a couple more options now.

Comment: `@property (readonly, getter=isConcurrent) BOOL concurrent; // To be deprecated; use and override 'asynchronous' below
@property (readonly, getter=isAsynchronous) BOOL asynchronous NS_AVAILABLE(10_8, 7_0);`

Comment: `Operation.isConcurrent`/`asyncronous` has nothing to do with whether the `OperationQueue` executing the operation has an underlying queue that is concurrent.